# FIlter and condense JSON file through queries

Tags: javascript, json

I have a .json file that is around 6MB and it built of identical object nodes like this:

```
{
     "category":"1153",
     "history":[
        {
           "expiration_date":"2020-07-15",
           "effective_date":"2020-07-15"
        },
        {
           "expiration_date":"2020-07-15",
           "effective_date":"2020-07-15"
        },
        {
           "expiration_date":"2020-07-15",
           "effective_date":"2020-07-15"
        },
        {
           "expiration_date":"2020-07-15",
           "effective_date":"2020-07-15"
        },
        {
           "expiration_date":"2020-07-15",
           "effective_date":"2020-07-15"
        },
        {
           "expiration_date":"9999-12-31",
           "effective_date":"2020-07-15"
        }
     ],
     "sellPrice":[
        {
           "price":"385.00",
           "price_category":"Clr",
        }
     ],
     "entered":"2020-07-15"
  },
```

My issue is that I want to remove the 'history' node/set altogether from every instance, but I also want to remove any instance that doesn't contain 'Clr' as the price_category.

I hope that makes sense but basically I want to remove the history section that I don't need and then I want my object to only be made of nodes that contain the 'Clr' option in price_category.

I may be able to do this through a lightweight online tool if I know the query or argument to use, but I could do it through my local code too

How can I properly filter this json set?

Comment: https://javascript.info/array-methods#reduce-reduceright

Comment: As @serraosays pointed out, you can use Reduce, or a combination of Filter and Map to transform your data. You can remove the history entries like this `data.map(({history, ...rest}) => ({...rest}))`. You can filter by price category with something like `data.filter(item => item.sellPrice[0].price_category !== 'Clr'` (but it won't deal with multiple entries in the `sellPrice` array.